# Angular2 Observable Timing?

Tags: angularjs, cookies

Use Case: Call a service (movies.service.ts) that will check to see if the data is in a cookie and if it is return the cookie data as JSON. If it isn't then call an http.get() endpoint and put the the data in the cookie and return that.

I believe my code for this is fine? However, when I call this service method from the component (movies.component.ts) it returns with 'undefined'. This is a timing issue. I need to be able to tell when it's done, before doing the console.log?

code below:

movies.service.ts

```
GetGenres() {
    //Check cookie first
    this.cookieService.delete('movie-genres');
    var cookieExists = this.cookieService.check('movie-genres');
    console.log(cookieExists);

    //if no cookie exists, call endpoint and set cookie
    if(!cookieExists) {
        //
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }); // ... Set content type to JSON
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); // Create a request option
        let url = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list?language=en-US&api_key=' + this.apiKeyV3;
        let dto = {  };
        //All endpoints currently accept only HTTP GET requests.
        var response = this.http.get(url, options)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);

        response
        .subscribe(
        res => {
            //next
            //this.genres = res.genres;
            console.log("next");
            this.cookieService.set('movie-genres', JSON.stringify(res.genres));
        },
        error => {
            var msg = { "Type": "Failure", "Message": <any>error };

        },
        () => { 
            //complete
            console.log('completed');  
            return this.cookieService.get('movie-genres');
        }
        );
    } 
    else {
        console.log('have cookie');  
        var cookie = this.cookieService.get('movie-genres');
        return cookie;
    }
}
```

movies.component.ts

```
 var response = this.moviesService.GetGenres();
 console.log(response); // this gets called before it finishes!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to paraphrase part of your code to show the problem:

```
 if(!cookieExists) {
      var response = // start making an async http request
      response.subscribe(
          // asynchronously handle the result of that request
      );
 }
```

Note that there is no "return" happening here.  You do have a return inside the async bit but that's not run "during" your function so it doesn't count.  This is why you are getting "undefined".  What you'll want to do is add `return response` after `response.subscribe()` and then the calller of this function can do `this.moviesService.GetGenres().subscribe( () => { ... }`.

Comment: How do I handle if the cookie exists it returns that, if not it returns an observable? can't really return two different types?

Comment: for that case, you wrap your value in an observable: `return Observable.of(cookie)`